# How to configure Google Cloud BigQuery in airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm trying add a connection in my **Apache Airflow** to connect to google cloud in order to use **BigQueryHook**, currently, I have my service account json file stored in `airflow-projects -> dags -> keys`. From the add connection in `Admin -> Connections`, I have specified
*Conn Id = bigquery_default*, *Conn Type = Google Cloud* and the *Keyfile Path=/keys/serviceKey.json*. When i run my dag, I'm getting an error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/keys/serviceKey.json'

I have tried to change Keyfile Path=/dags/keys/serviceKey.json* but still, I'm getting FileNotFoundError. What I'm I missing?

```
def get_data_from_bq(**kwargs):
    hook = BigQueryHook(bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default', delegate_to=None, use_legacy_sql=False)
    conn = hook.get_conn()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT owner_display_name, title, view_count FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` WHERE creation_date > "2020-09-09" ORDER BY view_count DESC LIMIT 2')
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print('result', result)
    return result
```

Comment: The easiest solution is just paste the full JSON in the Keyfile JSON section. That works

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure you key is available in the specific path for all your workers. You should check what is the path of your key when your worker is running. Your dags will usually be in `${AIRFLOW_HOME}/dags` so you need to check what the `${AIRFLOW_HOME}` points to and make your path absolute.

However this is likely not best way to authenticate, if you are using GCP/GKE to run your airflow workers, it would be better to use something like Workload identity: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity for example. Another option is to set ENV variables or use virtual machine credentials for your workers https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/best-practices-applications - in all cases those are default credentials that will be used if you do not specify any credentials in the hook.